# sklearn OneHotEncoder with ColumnTransformer resulting in sparse Matrix in place of creating dummies

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, sklearn-pandas, one-hot-encoding

I am trying to convert categorical value to integer using OneHotEncoder and ColumnTransformer. My understanding is it should create dummies for category columns like pd.get_dummies. My file is having ~1500 records and 10 columns.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
cat_features=['COMPANY_NAME', 'BRAND_NAME']
enc=OneHotEncoder()

transformer = ColumnTransformer([("enc", 
                                  enc,
                                  cat_features)],
                                  remainder="passthrough")
df_transformed = transformer.fit_transform(df_model)
df_transformed)
```

The result is:

```
<1574x37 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
    with 15513 stored elements in Compressed Sparse Row format>
```

When I try to look at the data after converting it into dataframe using:

[image]

What is wrong I am doing. My data looks something like below:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert it to a dense array before putting it into a data.frame, see [help page](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray.html) too:

```
pd.DataFrame(df_transformed.toarray())
```

Or you set the transformer to always return a dense array, see [the sparse threshold option](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.compose.ColumnTransformer.html)

```
transformer = ColumnTransformer([("enc", 
                                  enc,
                                  cat_features)],
                                  remainder="passthrough",sparse_threshold=0)
```